# How to do a string shadow span in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Been doing a bit of searching. I can see a method to add a shadow layer to a TextView, but I only want to shadow a span of text. I'm basically doing an EditText where user will be able to change style of text selections. One of those styles being a shadow with color of choice. There are spans for color, size, typeface, etc, but I cannot find something for shadows.

Basically I want to do something like:
(Note code is from Mono Droid, but a Java answer would be helpful as well)

```
        var N = new ShadowSpan(color,dx,dy,radius); // no such thing?
        int S = txEdit.SelectionStart;
        int E = txEdit.SelectionEnd;
        Str = new SpannableString(txEdit.TextFormatted);
        Str.SetSpan(N,S,E, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
        txEdit.SetText(Str, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        txEdit.SetSelection(S,E);
```

Any assistance or suggestion is appreciated. I'm wondering if I have to figure out how to derive my own ShadowSpan implementation from [android.text.style.CharacterStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html) (maybe override updateDrawState() to [setShadowLayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShadowLayer%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29) on the TextPaint object?) or perhaps I'm just missing the simple answer? I can't be the only one who has wanted to do this, so I'd thought I'd ask before going too far with trying something custom.

**-- EDIT --**

I tried creating my own ShadowSpan and it does seem to work. I'm still leaving the floor open if anyone has a better solution. It just seems like something should already exist, but I guess I didn't have to do too much.

Here is what I have in Mono for Android

```
public class ShadowSpan : Android.Text.Style.CharacterStyle
{
    public float Dx;
    public float Dy;
    public float Radius;
    public Android.Graphics.Color Color;
    public ShadowSpan(float radius, float dx, float dy, Android.Graphics.Color color)
    {
        Radius = radius; Dx = dx; Dy = dy; Color = color;
    }

    public override void UpdateDrawState (TextPaint tp)
    {
        tp.SetShadowLayer(Radius, Dx, Dy, Color);
    }
}
```

Used like so

```
    void HandleClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var N = new ShadowSpan(1,1,1,Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        int S = txEdit.SelectionStart;
        int E = txEdit.SelectionEnd;
        Str = new SpannableString(txEdit.TextFormatted);
        Str.SetSpan(N,S,E, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
        txEdit.SetText(Str, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        txEdit.SetSelection(S,E);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having thought about it more, it seems pretty simple to implement custom spans by deriving from CharacterStyle. I would guess Google didn't want to bloat the API with a bunch of one-off Span classes. I guess in the process of constructing my question I've ended up answering it. Well, hopefully this help someone else out some day. Thanks to all who posted suggestions.

```
public class ShadowSpan : Android.Text.Style.CharacterStyle
{
    public float Dx;
    public float Dy;
    public float Radius;
    public Android.Graphics.Color Color;
    public ShadowSpan(float radius, float dx, float dy, Android.Graphics.Color color)
    {
        Radius = radius; Dx = dx; Dy = dy; Color = color;
    }

    public override void UpdateDrawState (TextPaint tp)
    {
        tp.SetShadowLayer(Radius, Dx, Dy, Color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've done essentially what you've done, except in Java, and it works for me.

```
private static class ShadowStyleSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    private int radius;
    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int color;

    public ShadowStyleSpan(int radius, int dx, int dy, int color) {
        super();
        this.radius = radius;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy, color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd consider using [android:shadowColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ashadowColor), android:shadowDx, android:shadowDy, android:shadowRadius; alternatively [setShadowLayer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShadowLayer%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29).

check the [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/) it contains examples to customize text  (scroll down to Text Shadow section)

also see [this one](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/378)

Comment: I have seen this link. It sets the layer on the whole TextView, but I just want a sub-selection of the text.